# How to repeat the conditional statement until the choice is correct?

Tags: for-loop, go

In this code, I am trying to repeat the if-statement again if the condition is false or default but the loop stops at the default.

1. If I write `Scanln` inside the loop then it does not let me input the data
2. If I write `Scanln` outside the loop then it does not repeat the loop.

How to repeat the loop again and again until I enter the correct choice?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var choice int
    fmt.Printf("Enter your choice: ")
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&choice)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Letters or symbols not accepted")
    }

    for choice == 1 || choice == 2 {
        switch choice {
        case 1:
            fmt.Println("1 is selected")
        case 2:
            fmt.Println("2 is selected")
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Please enter the correct choice: ")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the loop to `for choice != 1 && choice != 2 { …`.  Move Scanln inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you, @CeriseLimón! It get solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script will get your work done.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var choice int

    for choice != 1 || choice != 2 {
        fmt.Printf("Enter your choice: ")
        _, err := fmt.Scanln(&choice)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Letters or symbols not accepted")
        }
        switch choice {
        case 1:
            fmt.Println("1 is selected")
        case 2:
            fmt.Println("2 is selected")
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Please enter the correct choice: ")
        }
    }
}
```